# What are the "Internal" and "Score" quality of fit numbers for FindDistribution?

Tags: fitting, distributions

This code:

```
\[ScriptCapitalD] = LogNormalDistribution[-3.3, 0.32];
data = RandomVariate[\[ScriptCapitalD], 1000];
estimated\[ScriptCapitalD] = FindDistribution[data, 5, All]
```

gives a table of distributions and quality of fit numbers.
What is the meaning of the "Internal" and "Score" quality of fit numbers? How are they calculated?

Comment: The documentation states "The internal information criterion uses a Bayesian information criterion together with priors over `TargetFunctions`."  This doesn't explain much (to me) as it's not clear what priors are used for each distribution.  The priors do seem consistent for each distribution considered although the prior seems to be influenced by sample size.  In short, I can't explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mathematica Tech Support said there should only be one column labeled "Internal score." He filed a bug report and also requested documentation to explain the source and meaning of the "Internal score."